# Is there any way i can add two lists in one foreach loop?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get my output in this format:

90 Jim
62 Amy

But the methods i've tried all output either:

90 Jim Amy  62 Jim Amy OR
90 62 Jim Amy

```
Console.WriteLine("_____________________\n\nThe resulting array:\n");

    foreach(var gradesof in grade)
   { 
    Console.WriteLine("  " + gradesof);

    //foreach(var namesof in name){
     //Console.WriteLine("  " + namesof);
   }
```

And in case someone might need the whole code:

```
using System;

namespace studentmanager {

public class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {

  Console.Write("\nInput number of students: ");
  var totalstudents = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    var name = new string [totalstudents]; //new string is creating an array of strings of the total number of studenys that were input initially
    var grade = new int [totalstudents];  //= {10,20,30,40,50}; since we're no longer hardcoding we don't need this part

    for (int i =0 ; i<totalstudents ; i++)
    {
     Console.WriteLine("\nInput student name: ");
      name [i] = Console.ReadLine(); //i is the index for the array
     Console.WriteLine("\nInput student grade: ");
      grade[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

  Console.WriteLine("_____________________\n\nThe resulting array:\n");

    foreach(var gradesof in grade)
   { 
    Console.WriteLine("  " + gradesof);

    //foreach(var namesof in name){
     //Console.WriteLine("  " + namesof);
   }

   }




  }
}
```

Comment: Try [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netcore-2.1).  Or better yet use a custom class or tuples to keep the values together in one array.

Comment: Create a cla class (say, StudentInfo) that has two properties, a string called Name and an int called Grade. Create an instance of this class for each student, adding each instance to a List<StudentInfo>. Now you can iterate through the list and get the names and grades for each student.

Comment: Is foreach a requirement for some reason? Why not just use a for loop from 0 to totalstudents and access the grades and names using the index? The only way foreach will work is if you have the grades and the names together in a single collection

Comment: Oh, and when parsing user entered data, you should always assume the user will mess up. Use int.TryParse rather than int.Parse

Comment: @Flydog57 i did try using tryparse but the parameter was causing a problem and i got error cs1501

Comment: That's telling you that you called it with the wrong number of parameters. That's what documentation is for. Try something like `while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var grade) || grade < 0 || grade > 100){Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 0 &100");}` This is phone coding, so it may be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already doing it with reading inputs. Instead of using `foreach` use a `for` loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < totalstudents; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{name[i]} {grade[i]}");
}
```

Comment: ok so i tried and its compiling but at the end im getting an error about unhandled exception with index being outside the bounds of the array

Comment: Ok i figured out why i was getting the out of bounds problem. it was because i should be < not <=

Comment: oh yeah my bad, ill change the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can make something like this

```
string mystring=String.Empty;
foreach(var student in school){
    mystring=String.Format("{0} {1} {2} ", mystring, student.Grade, student.Name);
}
Console.WriteLine("  " + mystring);
```